# What am I missing in order to swap numbers in this array? Java

Tags: java, arrays

So in my assignment, I'm halfway of solving this particular java array (this is an online book; percentage is at 50% in testing phase). However I cannot figure out what I'm missing. For this code, I have to make the input reverse two numbers (of whatever amount is requested). I tried looking online for similar situation but none answered what I needed.

**Directions:** Write a method swapArrayEnds() that swaps the first and last elements of its array parameter. Ex: sortArray = {10, 20, 30, 40} becomes {40, 20, 30, 10}. The array's size may differ from 4.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModifyArray {
// ANYTHING ABOVE THIS COMMENT CANNOT BE MODIFIED
   public static void swapArrayEnds(int[] sortArray, int numElem) {
      numElem = 4;
      int i = 0;         // Loop index
      int tmpStore = 0;  // Temp variable for swapping

      for (i = 0; i < numElem; ++i) {
         tmpStore = sortArray[i]; // Do swap
         sortArray[i] = sortArray[numElem - 1];
         sortArray[numElem - 1] = tmpStore;
      }

      return;
   }
// ANYTHING BELOW THIS COMMENT CANNOT BE MODIFIED
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      int numElem = 4;
      int[] sortArray = new int[numElem];
      int i = 0;

      sortArray[0] = 10;
      sortArray[1] = 20;
      sortArray[2] = 30;
      sortArray[3] = 40;

      swapArrayEnds(sortArray, numElem);

      for (i = 0; i < numElem; ++i) {
         System.out.print(sortArray[i]);
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println("");

      return;
   }
}
```

At the moment, my error code is:

```
Testing with original sortArray = {10, 20, 30, 40}
Expected output:  40 20 30 10 
Your output:  40 10 20 30 
Tests aborted.
```

I'm not sure how my input became like that, but it merely placed the original last number in front of the original first. How do I have it that the first and last numbers are swapped?

Comment: You swap each pair **twice**.

Comment: That's too vague for me. I'm still a beginner. I know I have to swap the first and last numbers, but where did I go wrong in my code or what am I missing?

Comment: @PM77-1 "You swap each pair twice.". **incorrect**: his code is a complicated right-roll-by-one. After first iteration, the first-last are swapped. At the second iteration, the second become last and the former-first-now-last becomes second - if effect rolling the former-first as now-the-second and letting the second on-top-of-stack. And so on, until the last iteration where the "swap" is degenerated (element swapped with itself).

Comment: So, I suppose I humored myself and added `i++` twice after `sortArray[numElem - 1] = tmpStore;` and that got me my first answer. However, it was not accepted as a whole due to this error message.

`Runtime error (commonly due to an invalid array/vector access, divide by 0, etc.).
Tests aborted."`

Comment: You are only swapping two numbers.  There is no reason to have a loop in your code.

Comment: Don't use a for loop. Just do a one time swap of element at 0 and elment at size() - 1, using a temp variable.

Comment: why is there a loop ?

Comment: @Jameson, thanks for the tip! The loop was throwing me off! I was just following the pattern of the code for using the for statement and thought I had to do something similar.

Comment: side note: you may tell your teacher that `return` statements at the end of a `void` are not necessary, and from my experience unusual, and even discouraged and confusing.

Comment: @njzk2, okay. Thanks for the side note! I'll keep it in mind when I'm doing my assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **only** the ends need to be swapped, and this swap need to happen **exactly once** (not repeatedly), how about:

```
  // Why do you need yo swap it in a cycle, thus many times???
  /* Commenting faulty code out
  for (i = 0; i < numElem; ++i) {
     tmpStore = sortArray[i]; // Do swap
     sortArray[i] = sortArray[numElem - 1];
     sortArray[numElem - 1] = tmpStore;
  }
  */

  // A single time should do
  tmpStore = sortArray[0]; // Do swap with the starting end
  sortArray[0] = sortArray[numElem - 1];
  sortArray[numElem - 1] = tmpStore;
```

---

(note: I think I'm getting tired of inane comments/answers sending a beginner on fool's errands)

Comment: Thank you for the note, I thought it was normal for answers to be hinted at seeing that was what I commonly saw for other posts. I didn't see your answer in time when I submitted my final code, however your answer is nearly identical to what I did submit.

Comment: To be a good programmer, you need to lean how to "translate" between natural language and code **in both directions**. I'm sure that, if you have done the reverse translation with your code as input, you would have realized what was happening by yourself (and  would have not raised the questions). Practice more the "describe in your own words what this code is doing" and you'll grow quick.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void swapArrayEnds(int sortArray[],int numElem ) {

int t;

t = sortArray[numElem-1];   

//assigning last element to temporary variable

sortArray[numElem-1]=sortArray[0];

//swapping last element with first element

sortArray[0]=t;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this approach outlined below.

```
   public static void swapArrayEnds(int[] newArray){

      int num = newArray[0] ;
      newArray[0] = newArray[newArray.length-1];
      newArray[newArray.length-1] = num;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

package net.code.java;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModifyArray {

```
public static void swapArrayEnds(int[] sortArray) {
    int temp = 0; 
    
    temp = sortArray[0]; 
    sortArray[0] = sortArray[sortArray.length-1]; 
    sortArray[sortArray.length-1] = temp; 
    return; 
}


public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numElem = 4;
      int[] sortArray = new int[numElem];
      int i;
      int userNum;

      for (i = 0; i < sortArray.length; ++i) {
         sortArray[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      }

      swapArrayEnds(sortArray);

      for (i = 0; i < sortArray.length; ++i) {
         System.out.print(sortArray[i]);
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
//a fix the the first answer provided    
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModifyArray {
// ANYTHING ABOVE THIS COMMENT CANNOT BE MODIFIED
      for (int i = 0; i < numElem; i++) {
         int temp = sortArray[i]; 
         sortArray[i] = sortArray[numElem - 1];
         sortArray[numElem - 1] = temp;
         return;
      }
   }
// ANYTHING BELOW THIS COMMENT CANNOT BE MODIFIED
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      int numElem = 4;
      int[] sortArray = new int[numElem];
      int i = 0;

      sortArray[0] = 10;
      sortArray[1] = 20;
      sortArray[2] = 30;
      sortArray[3] = 40;

      swapArrayEnds(sortArray, numElem);

      for (i = 0; i < numElem; ++i) {
         System.out.print(sortArray[i]);
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println("");

      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: i just put the return statement inside swapArrayEnds method so that it always outputs the new reversed numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static void swapArrayEnds(int sortArray [],int numElem) {

     int temp = sortArray[0]; 
     sortArray[0] = sortArray[numElem - 1];
     sortArray[numElem - 1] = temp;
  }
```

Comment: you don't need to use a for loop... just assign the first to the last and the last to the first. The main gives you the numElem and sortArray so you don't need it to look at each number.

Comment: Please add your comments to your answer by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55250920/edit) it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ModifyArray {

   /* Your solution goes here  */
   public static void swapArrayEnds(int[] arr) {
      int temp = arr[0];
      arr[0] = arr[arr.length-1];
      arr[arr.length-1] = temp;
   }
   
   
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int numElem = 4;
      int[] sortArray = new int[numElem];
      int i;
      int userNum;

      for (i = 0; i < sortArray.length; ++i) {
         sortArray[i] = scnr.nextInt();
      }

      swapArrayEnds(sortArray);

      for (i = 0; i < sortArray.length; ++i) {
         System.out.print(sortArray[i]);
         System.out.print(" ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
   }
}
```